# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: Trigger Specific Stage In Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline and wonder whether if there is any way to trigger specific stage only periodically or not.

What I mean when we checkout SCM, pipeline triggers but Stage 2 takes too long for some of our projects.Thus rather than waiting this stage I would like to run this stage only daily basis but still keep this stage in jenkinsfile.

Is there any way to achieve this? What might be the best approach of doing this?

```
    stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Stage 2') {
      triggers {
        cron('H H 0 0 0')
        }
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: @Altaf, I am trying now but the confusion is how the pipeline is trigger ? What I mean how it can be start without trigger it? What I want it needs to be trigger without SCM, like how`triggers{}` is doing

Comment: @seumral : you can trigger from jenkins configuration under Build Triggers section, so you will not need to add it in pipeline script

Comment: @Altaf, so will it trigger only this stage or complete pipeline ?

Answer (score 3):

Please see below code / method which will give you an idea of how to execute specific stage at a specific day or at a specific condition.You can change the conditions based on your requirement
Use plugin Timestamper https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/ to get timestamp releated infos.

```
# Get the day from the build timestamp
def getday = env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP
getday = getday .split(" ")
// Extract current day
getday = getday [3]
pipeline 
{
  agent any
 options { timestamps () }
 stages {
 stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }

 stage('Stage 2') {
      when 
            {
                // Note: You can change condition as per your need
                // Stage will run only when the day is Mon 
                expression {
                     getday == "Mon"
                }
            }
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Configure BuildTimestamp**:
If your build time stamp is not configured to get day information, then you can  do it using below method 
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/ 
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Build Timestamp -> Click on Enable BUILD_TIMESTAMP. 
 Put Pattern as :**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z EEE**

**Please note** : Triggeres directive is available in jenkins pipeline as shown below where you could put your cron condition but it will be executed for all the stages and not for a single stage.

```
// Declarative //
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H H 0 0 0')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            script {
                  // do something
                )
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not able to fix an error `Invalid option type "timestamps"`.. Is it requires a plugin ? Jenkins 2.263.4 is the version

Comment: @semural : yes you can use plugin Timestamper `https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/`.

Comment: unfortunately I had another error.. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`..The output of env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP is 2021-05-14 12:50:35 CEST.. I could not see the weekday info

Comment: @semural: Oh you need to then configure it : Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Build Timestamp -> Click on Enable BUILD_TIMESTAMP. Set Pattern : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z EEE. Added this info in answer now

Comment: I can able to get the day via another way but maybe its my fault to not clarify my case properly..Day is not proper parameter maybe or maybe no way to do this.. Lets say today is friday and ı checkout the development branch.. Due to its friday it will work again but what I want it should be trigger automatically without checkout but only this stage should be run in the pipeline daily

Comment: @semural yes you can achieve this by just adding conditions on each stage when you would like to execute it.Flow would be : Pipeline file would be called every time and stages will be executed only based on the conditions

Comment: ı've already but the issue is each weekday meet the conditions somehow.. If I specify weekend then somehow ı need to trigger pipeline with day parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232435/discussion-between-altaf-and-semural).